# how to extract the value from a column in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to achieve the operation among certain values of a column. Here is part of my code:

```
   for line in rdf_f:
    iendbead = nstart + i * 45
    fields = line.split()
    if len(fields) > 1:
        z = fields[3]
        dz = abs(Zface - z(iendbead))
```

However, I cannot target the values`z(iendbead)`, and encounter an error says:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here z is column:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Since `z` is a string, it's not entirely clear what you intend `z(iendbead)` to do. A string is not a function. Are you trying to extract a particular character from that string? Or multiply the integer value of the string by something? Or ???

Answer (score 1):

Use `z[iendbead]` instead of `z(iendbead)`.

`[]` is the operator to access an array item, among other things, `()` is for calling functions (or creating generators).

Comment: I tried already, but because Z is a column, the system shows error:IndexError: string index out of range.

Comment: Well, your iendbead must be in range so, you need to rethink your problem.